# Сервер для java web service

Tags: java, сервер, servlet, веб-сервер

У нас есть андроид приложение взаимодействующее с сервером. Расчитываем на 15-20 тысяч клиентов. Делаем что-то вроде социальной сети. Работа в потоках, взаимодействие с бд и другими сервисами. Какой сервер лучше выбрать для данных условий? Характеристики и стоимость сервера, а так же, если можно ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего у вас будет json формат данных, без EJB, SOAP и т.д. сервер-контейнер Apache Tomcat покроет все ваши задачи. Если хотите хайлоад и хардкор решение, то Netty.

Comment: нам нужно не сервера по типу tomcat'a glassfish'a и т.д., а серверное ПО, по типу openshift'a и amazon'а

Comment: @NursultanZhyenbaev, То есть вопрос в том, какое железо вам нужно?

Comment: @Nofate да характеристики железа и желательно ссылки на них, спасибо)